# PowerPoint, click and open external file during presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

is it possible? During presentation on some slide I click on some part of the slide and then the OS opens some external file with its associated program.

Comment: What sort of file?

Comment: it is whatever kind of file. i.e., PDF, etc. I am using mac office 2008 and it should work with "inser hyperlink" but it does not!

Comment: for solving the problem one has to put the linked files on the same folder than the presentation file. otherwise one gets problems

Comment: Yeah ideally one could embed the file in the ppt but this does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 5):

Just right-click on an object (image, text, etc.), select "Hyperlink..." and then select the file you want opened. Note that clicking the object only works in presentation mode.

Answer (score 1):

At least in PowerPoint 2013 you cloud use following technique:

edit: Sorry, I thought this was about opening embedded file.

[image]